# npm specify where require package-name/module-name points to

Tags: node.js, npm

Consider the following folder structure:

```
- lib
  + main.js
  + optional.js
- src
  + main.coffee
  + optional.coffee
+ package.json
```

I can specify the main file in `package.json` no problem with:

```
  "main": "./lib/main",
```

But when I `require('package-name/optional')` I want `./lib/optional`. How can I specify that / make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't possible, because module names are resolved as paths for the required script.

The reason you can specify a `main` option is because `package-name` resolves to `node_modules/package-name` (where `package.json` can be found) whereas `package-name/option` will resolve to `node_modules/package-name/option` which is an entirely different path.

If you'd like to see how the module paths are resolved, you can take a look in the Node source [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L224). The order of functions that lead to path resolution looks like this:

```
Module.prototype.require
Module._load
Module._resolveFilename
Module._resolveLookupPaths
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify files/folders under the package name, but as hexacyanide has pointed out, it isn't possible to specify a custom require option for that specific file. For example:

```
require('package-name/lib/optional')
```